# Yanking and pasting while incrementing

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I am editing a .sql file in Vim:

```
INSERT INTO apps_forms (app_id, form_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
```

What I'm looking to do is yank the `(1, 1),` line and paste it 137 times; however, I want the *second* number in parenthesis to be incremented each time. The output would look like:

```
INSERT INTO apps_forms (app_id, form_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
...
(1, 137),
```

Is there a way to do that in Vim and, if so, what command would I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put your cursor on the `(1, 1),` line then type :

```
qaVypt)<C-a>q135@a
```

Explanation :

`qa` begins the recording of a macro inside the register **a** (you could choose another letter).

`Vyp` duplicates the current line, by selecting the whole line (V), copying it (y) and then pasting it below (p).

`t)` move the cursor just before the next closed parenthesis, so that it's on the second number.

`<C-a>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>) increments the number.

`q` ends the recording of the macro.

`135@a` replays the macro stored in the register **a** 135 times.

Edit : [Peter Rincker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/yanking-and-pasting-while-incrementing/5437#comment8342_5437) has a shorter command :

```
qqYpW<c-a>q135@q
```

The differences are :

it uses the register **q** to store the macro (faster to type `qq` than `qa` because it's the same key),
it copies the line with only one keystroke `Y` (instead of two `Vy`),
and it moves the cursor to the second number with only one keystroke `W` (instead of `t)`).

Comment: Vim golf: `qqyypW<c-a>q135@q`. Even shorter if you use `Y` instead of `yy`.

Answer (score 12):

Recent Vims have learned about incrementing visual selected regions as well as creating a sequence. So you can do this after pasting your line 137 times:

1) visually block-select (<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>) the second 1 starting from line 3.

2) press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>

I have recorded a screen cast [here](https://www.256bit.org/~chrisbra/Vim_Recording_20151109.mkv)

Disclaimer: This needs a Vim 7.4.900 or so.

Comment: Successfully tested in Vim 7.4.826 on Debian/sid.

Comment: Your screencast has disappeared but this method is AWESOME! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easy to understand / easy to remember / easy to adapt to other situations way to do it: use the [VisIncr](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VISINCR) plugin (if you'd rather use a version that actually plays nice with the package managers from this century as opposed to dealing with `vimball`s, you can get it from [GitHub](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VisIncr)).  With it:

- go to the `(1, 1),` line and yank it: `Vy`
- paste it 136 times: `136p`
- go to the second column of `1` and mark it vertically: `C-vGf)h`
- run the increment: `:II`
- read the manual to find out about the other goodies: `:help visincr`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd play with `g^a`.

Try `137i0^v137kg^a`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’ve formatted your answer using markdown. It would be even better if you [edit] to explain how this answers OPs question.