# Increment the number at the end of variable

Tags: text-generation

In my `C` code I am dealing with many variables of type

```
RxMsgType0
RxMsgType1
RxMsgType2
RxMsgType3
...
```

My Question:  Is there a way in VIM by which I can create 4 more variables which follow the same format?

Expected output: [Type Some Command]

```
RxMsgType4
RxMsgType5
RxMsgType6
RxMsgType7
```

In the future I would like to pass the

```
name (RxMsgType assumed here ) 

number( we assumed 4 here)
```

as an argument to get the variable names formed.

That is my final aim.

Comment: Related post: [Yanking and pasting while incrementing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5436/778)

Comment: @PeterRincker's link is probably what you want. And to make it persistent, you could dedicate a register to it, e.g `i` and so put in your vimrc : `let @i='yyp^A'` where `^A` is the actual `CTRL-A` character that you can insert with `<c-v><c-a>`. Than you can do `[count]@i`. Note that this increases *the first number* on the line. If you have a more complex line, add a line-motion between `yyp` and `^A` to place your cursor in the right spot. Also consider looking `:help nrformats`

Comment: Code review: have you considered using an array instead?

Comment: @perelo `let @i = "yyp\<C-A>"`, using double quotes allow using `\<...>` to refer to keystrokes by name, so no need to insert a special character in vimrc for that. Using a mapping is also possible (though I actually quite like the idea of the dedicated register!)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Interestingly enough, that would probably only change the current question from `RxMsgType4` to `RxMsgType[4]` :-P

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution if you are using vim 8 using the `g<c-A>` command:

- paste the variable n times

```
RxMsgType0
RxMsgType0
RxMsgType0
RxMsgType0

... n times

RxMsgType0
```

- select all line wise e.g if that's the whole file `gg <s-V> G`
- use `g <c-A>`